# Mobile app showing other users' exact location

Tags: cordova, gps

If I were to attempt to create a mobile application (cordova/webapi/sql server app) that allows the user to see the exact location of other users, I'm guessing that I would have to gather the exact location of the user when the app is launched and store that in a user sessions table. I could then use something like signalr to poll that table and send updates to the app. Does this sound reasonable? Is there an easier way? Is there a flaw in my thinking?

This assumes that the user would allow the app to gather their location.

**EDIT**
In an effort to narrow down the focus of the question, there are essentially a few questions I have:

1. Is there a way using cordova to "track" a user's location at timed intervals, like say every 5 minutes?
2. Does doing this cause a significant drain on the device's battery?

Is something like this feasible? Hopefully, this narrows it down a little.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you can use cordova-plugin-geolocation plugin in order to access a geolocation of a device. And:
ad 1: use JavaScript's #setInterval() or #setTimeout() functions in order to add timing events
ad 2: no, it should not.